# How to use knockout mapping plugin with Durandal?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, durandal

I'm new in Durandal, and wanted to rewrite my existing knockout project using this framework. In my old project I'm using knockout mapping plugin and now I have problem with it. I work with Durandal sample project as a base. Here is my piece of code:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/system', 'knockout'], function (app, system, ko) {

    var clients = ko.observableArray([]);

    return {    
        clients: clients,

        activate: function(data) {
            var self = this;
            ko.mapping.fromJS(getData(), {}, self.clients);
        }
    };
};
```

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fromJS' of undefined

Indeed, it is undefined, but where should I add it and make it working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the mapping plugin in the `define`otherwise is not going to load it.

```
define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/system', 'knockout', 'knockout-mapping'], function (app, system, ko) {
```

Make sure you able to load this script like this in your requirejs configuration.

I suggest that you load Knockout and the mapping plugin in the `main.js`so you don't need to keep "requiring" them in all the viewmodels. You can also bundle them separately and not be part of the loader.

Comment: The last paragraph doesn't seem like a good idea. Please clarify what you mean?
How would you test the module by itself if the dependencies are defined elsewhere?

Comment: I agree in terms of  testing that might be a good idea to add Knockout as a dependency in the module. However, if you think as Knockout as a 3rd party library (not as a module  that you want to test) I think it doesn't make sense to put it in all the modules. IMO knockout should be a library that belongs to the core of the system, not to a specific module.